# how to modify jks file

Tags: unix, certificate, keytool

We are in need of a fix to our trust.jks. I have been told the CN contains spaces (I was told it was created on a Windows box and/or Windows can work with the CN containing spaces.) The unix system requires (we believe) periods instead of spaces.

Can the CN in the trust.jks be modified without having to go back to our cert requestor for a new trust.jks?  (It would be somewhat problematic from a logistics standpoint).

No one here is a 'cert-guy' so I'm reaching out - could find nothing specific to my question - all searches regarded creating a trust.jks - not modifying it.

Comment: sorry, but cert files are meant to be "problematic". There's a limited amount that you can do with rebuilding a complete key store, but from my experience, you can only add or remove keys. Will be happy to be proved wrong. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the new keypair already, and just want to alter the keystore - this is possible using openssl and re-importing the keys, although it is a bit complicated if you have no experience yet.

If you want to change the CN of a signed certificate, that is not possible. The CN is part of the signing process, so it can only be changed by creating a new signature.